# JavaFX export LineChart to png doesn't render the chart correctly if the chart is not brought to foreground

Tags: javafx, linechart

In a JavaFX application, I have a tab pane with one of the tabs containing a lineChart.  I am trying to export the image of the lineChart.  The image being exported appears distorted (incorrect label / axis / number alignment) if i don't visit the tab before exporting the image.

```
SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(getNode().snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null), null);
```

If i goto the tab, view the graph and then export the image, the images look correct.

[Distorted graph exported without viewing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mfAu.png)

[Correct graph exported after viewing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr11y.png)

The example below has two tabs
mainTab and chartTab.  mainTab has two buttons btnCompute to compute the values & draw the chart.  btnSaveChart to save the chart to png.
chartTab - Contains the chart.

```
public class ChartExport extends Application {

    LineChart<Number, Number> chart;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab mainTab = new Tab("Main Tab");
        Tab chartTab = new Tab("Chart Tab");
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(mainTab, chartTab);

        Button btnCompute = new Button();
        btnCompute.setText("Compute");
        btnCompute.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                    series.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(n, Math.pow(n, 4)));
                }

                chart.getData().add(series);                
            }
        });

        Button btnSaveChart = new Button();
        btnSaveChart.setText("Save Chart");
        btnSaveChart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                BufferedImage img = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null), null);
                
                chart.applyCss();
                Parent p = (Parent)chart;
                p.applyCss();
                
                try {
                    File file = new File("chart.png");
                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().add(btnCompute);
        vBox.getChildren().add(btnSaveChart);

        mainTab.setContent(vBox);

        // create tab for chart
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("x axis - i");
        yAxis.setLabel("y axis - i ^ 4");
        chart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setTitle("power of 4");
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);

        chartTab.setContent(chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Graph Export");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void launchApp() { 
        launch();
    }
```

I believe the node doesn’t complete rendering the graph unless its brought to front.  Is there a way to force complete rendering the node / graph (even if its not been brought to foreground) ?  I am running openJDK17.04.  This is in someway related to [29721289](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721289/how-to-generate-chart-image-using-javafx-chart-api-for-export-without-displying) but I am actually rendering the chart for the user to see (though some of them may be in panes the user has not selected / seen).

I have tried a few options to see if i can force changes / rendering of a graph when the node is not in the foreground but none of these seem to work.

```
this.chart.setAnimated(false);
this.chart.setCache(false);

chart.disable(true);
chart.disable(false);

chart.setVisible(false);
chart.setVisible(true);
```

and one suggested by [slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw)

```
chart.applyCss();
chart.getParent().layout();
```

Would appreciate any other solutions / ideas to force rendering of the node when it hasn't been brought to foreground.

Comment: [mcve] required for debugging questions.

Comment: If [`jfreechart-fx`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart-fx/info) its an option, you can ask the chart for a [`BufferedImage`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html).

Comment: Try calling `applyCss()` followed by a call to `layout()` on each graph before snapshotting them. You mention use of a tab pane. I don't remember exactly how that control is implemented, but it's possible a tab's content is either set `visable = false` or completely removed from the greater scene graph when that tab is not selected. In the latter case, and probably for the former case as well, JavaFX will not perform a layout pass on the tab content because there's no reason to. But `applyCss()` followed by `layout()` mimics a layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues exporting distorted images of a LineChart in JavaFX, you can try the following approach to ensure the chart is properly rendered before exporting the image:

Make sure to call chart.applyCss() and chart.layout() before calling chart.snapshot() to ensure the chart is properly laid out and styled.
Also, make sure to visit the tab containing the chart before exporting the image to ensure the chart has been properly initialized.

```html
public class ChartExport extends Application {

    LineChart<Number, Number> chart;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab mainTab = new Tab("Main Tab");
        Tab chartTab = new Tab("Chart Tab");
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(mainTab, chartTab);

        Button btnCompute = new Button();
        btnCompute.setText("Compute");
        btnCompute.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                    series.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(n, Math.pow(n, 4)));
                }

                chart.getData().add(series);                
            }
        });

        Button btnSaveChart = new Button();
        btnSaveChart.setText("Save Chart");
        btnSaveChart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                chart.applyCss();
                chart.layout();

                WritableImage image = chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);

                try {
                    File file = new File("chart.png");
                    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().add(btnCompute);
        vBox.getChildren().add(btnSaveChart);

        mainTab.setContent(vBox);

        // create tab for chart
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("x axis - i");
        yAxis.setLabel("y axis - i ^ 4");
        chart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setTitle("power of 4");
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);

        chartTab.setContent(chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Graph Export");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void launchApp() { 
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My main problem is that the graph needs to be rendered correctly if the user doesnt visit the tab / graph.  It is rendered if the graph / tab holding the graph gets visited.